# SSE much slower than regular function

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, windows-forms-designer, sse

i am making Julia set visualisation using SSE.
here is my code
class and operators

```
class vec4 {
    public:
        inline vec4(void) {}
        inline vec4(__m128 val) :v(val) {}

        __m128 v;

        inline void operator=(float *a) {v=_mm_load_ps(a);}
        inline vec4(float *a) {(*this)=a;} 
        inline vec4(float a) {(*this)=a;}

        inline void operator=(float a) {v=_mm_load1_ps(&a);}

};

inline vec4 operator+(const vec4 &a,const vec4 &b) { return _mm_add_ps(a.v,b.v); }
inline vec4 operator-(const vec4 &a,const vec4 &b) { return _mm_sub_ps(a.v,b.v); }
inline vec4 operator*(const vec4 &a,const vec4 &b) { return _mm_mul_ps(a.v,b.v); }
inline vec4 operator/(const vec4 &a,const vec4 &b) { return _mm_div_ps(a.v,b.v); }
inline vec4 operator++(const vec4 &a)
{
    __declspec(align(16)) float b[4]={1.0f,1.0f,1.0f,1.0f};
    vec4 B(b);
    return _mm_add_ps(a.v,B.v); 
}
```

function itself:

```
vec4 TWO(2.0f);
vec4 FOUR(4.0f);
vec4 ZER(0.0f);

vec4 CR(cR);
vec4 CI(cI);

for (int i=0; i<320; i++) //H
{
    float *pr = (float*) _aligned_malloc(4 * sizeof(float), 16); //dynamic

    __declspec(align(16)) float pi=i*ratioY + startY;

    for (int j=0; j<420; j+=4) //W
    {

        pr[0]=j*ratioX + startX;
        for(int x=1;x<4;x++)
        {
            pr[x]=pr[x-1]+ratioX;
        }

        vec4 ZR(pr);
        vec4 ZI(pi);

        __declspec(align(16)) float color[4]={0.0f,0.0f,0.0f,0.0f};

        vec4 COLOR(color);
        vec4 COUNT(0.0f);

        __m128 MASK=ZER.v;

        int _count;
        enum {max_count=100};
        for (_count=0;_count<=max_count;_count++) 
        {

            vec4 tZR=ZR*ZR-ZI*ZI+CR;
            vec4 tZI=TWO*ZR*ZI+CI;
            vec4 LEN=tZR*tZR+tZI*tZI;

            __m128 MASKOLD=MASK;
            MASK=_mm_cmplt_ps(LEN.v,FOUR.v);

            ZR=_mm_or_ps(_mm_and_ps(MASK,tZR.v),_mm_andnot_ps(MASK,ZR.v));
            ZI=_mm_or_ps(_mm_and_ps(MASK,tZI.v),_mm_andnot_ps(MASK,ZI.v));

            __m128 CHECKNOTEQL=_mm_cmpneq_ps(MASK,MASKOLD);    
            COLOR=_mm_or_ps(_mm_and_ps(CHECKNOTEQL,COUNT.v),_mm_andnot_ps(CHECKNOTEQL,COLOR.v));

            COUNT=COUNT++;
            operations+=17;

            if (_mm_movemask_ps((LEN-FOUR).v)==0) break; 
        }
        _mm_store_ps(color,COLOR.v);
```

SSE needs 553k operations (mull,add,if) and takes ~320ms to finish the task
from the other hand regular function takes 1428k operations but need only ~90ms to compute?
I used vs2010 performance analyser and seems that all maths operators are running rly slow. 
What I am doing wrong?

Comment: You might want to double-check that your inlined operator functions actually **are** being inlined. I've done something similar before, and it turned out that VS refused to inline the functions even when declared with `inline`. So I ended up needing to use `__forceinline`.

Comment: It might also help if you post a fully self-contained example that showed this difference. The code you have shown isn't compilable by itself.

Comment: I'm not sure that SIMD is appropriate for this algorithm since the number of iterations you need to do can be different for each point. GPUs might fair better or even parallelising by cpu core.

Comment: I Second Mysticial's comment above. Providing self-contained examples of both implementations (SSE and non-SSE) is needed to really identify where the problems are. Also, what optimization level are you using? At low optimization levels, the compiler might be doing silly things, especially with all those temporary `vec4` variables that get generated in the inner loop.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The problem you are having is that the SSE intrinics are doing far more memory operations than the non-SSE version. Using your vector class I wrote this:

```
int main (int argc, char *argv [])
{
  vec4 a (static_cast <float> (argc));
  cout << "argc = " << argc << endl;
  a=++a;
  cout << "a = (" << a.v.m128_f32 [0] << ", " << a.v.m128_f32 [1] << ", " << a.v.m128_f32 [2] << ", " << a.v.m128_f32 [3] << ", " << ")" << endl;
}
```

which produced the following operations in a release build (I've edited this to show the SSE only):

```
fild        dword ptr [ebp+8] // load argc into FPU
fstp        dword ptr [esp+10h] // save argc as a float

movss       xmm0,dword ptr [esp+10h] // load argc into SSE
shufps      xmm0,xmm0,0 // copy argc to all values in SSE register
movaps      xmmword ptr [esp+20h],xmm0 // save to stack frame

fld1 // load 1 into FPU
fst         dword ptr [esp+20h] 
fst         dword ptr [esp+28h] 
fst         dword ptr [esp+30h] 
fstp        dword ptr [esp+38h] // create a (1,1,1,1) vector
movaps      xmm0,xmmword ptr [esp+2Ch] // load above vector into SSE
addps       xmm0,xmmword ptr [esp+1Ch] // add to vector a
movaps      xmmword ptr [esp+38h],xmm0 // save back to a
```

Note: the addresses are relative to ESP and there are a few pushes which explains the weird changes of offset for the same value.

Now, compare the code to this version:

```
int main (int argc, char *argv [])
{
  float a[4];
  for (int i = 0 ; i < 4 ; ++i)
  {
    a [i] = static_cast <float> (argc + i);
  }
  cout << "argc = " << argc << endl;
  for (int i = 0 ; i < 4 ; ++i)
  {
    a [i] += 1.0f;
  }
  cout << "a = (" << a [0] << ", " << a [1] << ", " << a [2] << ", " << a [3] << ", " << ")" << endl;
}
```

The compiler created this code for the above (again, edited and with weird offsets)

```
fild        dword ptr [argc] // converting argc to floating point values
fstp        dword ptr [esp+8] 
fild        dword ptr [esp+4] // the argc+i is done in the integer unit
fstp        dword ptr [esp+0Ch] 
fild        dword ptr [esp+8] 
fstp        dword ptr [esp+18h]
fild        dword ptr [esp+10h]
fstp        dword ptr [esp+24h] // array a now initialised

fld         dword ptr [esp+8] // load a[0]
fld1 // load 1 into FPU
fadd        st(1),st // increment a[0]
fxch        st(1)
fstp        dword ptr [esp+14h] // save a[0]
fld         dword ptr [esp+1Ch] // load a[1]
fadd        st,st(1) // increment a[1]
fstp        dword ptr [esp+24h] // save a[1]
fld         dword ptr [esp+28h] // load a[2]
fadd        st,st(1) // increment a[2]
fstp        dword ptr [esp+28h]  // save a[2]
fadd        dword ptr [esp+2Ch] // increment a[3]
fstp        dword ptr [esp+2Ch] // save a[3]
```

In terms of memory access, the increment requires:

```
SSE                  FPU
4xfloat write        1xfloat read
1xsse read           1xfloat write
1xsse read+add       1xfloat read
1xsse write          1xfloat write
                     1xfloat read
                     1xfloat write
                     1xfloat read
                     1xfloat write

total
8 float reads        4 float reads
8 float writes       4 float writes
```

This shows the SSE is using twice the memory bandwidth of the FPU version and memory bandwidth is a major bottleneck.

If you want to seriously maximise the SSE then you need to write the whole aglorithm in a single SSE assembler function so that you can eliminate the memory read/writes as much as possible. Using the intrinsics is not an ideal solution for optimisation.

Comment: Forgot to say: the above assembler was generated by VS2005.

Answer (score 0):

here is an another example(Mandelbrot Sets) which is almost same to mine way of implementation of the Julia set algoritm
http://pastebin.com/J90paPVC based on http://www.iquilezles.org/www/articles/sse/sse.htm.
same story FPU>SSE I even skip some irrelevant operations.
any ideas how to do it right?

Comment: The problem is that the algorithm behaves differently for different inputs which is the opposite of what SSE does - SIMD = Single Instruction Multiple Data, the algorithm must behave the same for different inputs.

Comment: i was able to "fix" the problem ,however I don't understand why it happens like this!instead of debugging in vs I have realised the program from it and then run exe. Unexpectedly SSE started working 3 times faster then nonSSE.does anyone know what compiler optimizes when its deal with sse code?